# XSLT modify identity rule with string matching

Tags: xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0

I need to create an XSLT to follow two rules (in order of priority):

1. Should copy the entire `/xs:schema/node()` in which `/xs:schema/node()/@name` starts with "prefix_". This `/xs:schema/node()` should include all the descendants and attributes.
2. Should create a `/xs:schema/node()` containing **only** the descendants with *any* attribute that starts with "prefix_"

The document I have follows this format

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
    this is
    a really long
    comment
    that spans
    multiple lines
-->
<!-- <!a comment > another comment -->
<!-- <!a comment > another comment -->
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="unqualified"
    attributeFormDefault="unqualified">

    <!-- a comment -->
    <xs:node name="ABC">
        <xs:node>
            <xs:element/>
            <xs:element attr="asdf"/>
        </xs:node>
    </xs:node>
    <!-- <!a comment > another comment -->
    <node name="DEF">
        <element/>
        <element attr="asdf" bttr="zxcv"/>
    </node>
    <!-- <!a comment > another comment -->
    <node name="prefix_a">
        <element/>
        <element attr="asdf"/>
        <element attr="prefix_attr"/>
        <element battr="prefix_battr"/>
    </node>

    <node name="prefix_b">
        <node>
            <element/>
            <element battr="prefix_bttr"/>
            <element hattr="prefix_cattr"/>
        </node>
    </node>

    <node name="c">
        <node>
            <node>
                <node>
                    <node>
                        <element attr="qwerty"/>
                        <element attr="zxvc"/>
                        <element attr="asdf"/>
                        <element battr="prefix_bttr"/>
                        <element flattr="prefix_hattr"/>
                    </node>
                </node>
            </node>
        </node>
    </node>

    <node name="d">
        <element/>
        <element attr="asdf"/>
        <element shattr="prefix_shattr"/>
        <element cattr="prefix_battr"/>
    </node>
    <!-- <!a comment > another comment -->
    <node name="g">
        <element attr="asdf" bttr="zxcv"/>
        <element/>
    </node>

</xs:schema>
```

The XSLT should return;

```
<xml>
<xs:schema>

  <node name="prefix_a">
    <element />
    <element attr="asdf" />
    <element attr="prefix_attr" />
    <element battr="prefix_battr" />
  </node>

  <node name="prefix_b">
    <node>
      <element />
      <element battr="prefix_bttr" />
      <element hattr="prefix_cattr" />
    </node>
  </node>

  <node name="c">
    <node>
      <node>
        <node>
          <node>
            <element battr="prefix_bttr" />
            <element flattr="prefix_hattr" />
          </node>
        </node>
      </node>
    </node>
  </node>

  <node name="d">
    <element shattr="prefix_shattr" />
    <element cattr="prefix_battr" />
  </node>

</xs:schema>
```

I am using the following XSLT below;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

    <xsl:namespace-alias stylesheet-prefix="xs" result-prefix="xsd"/>

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="xsd:schema"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="xsd:schema">
        <xs:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="unqualified"
            attributeFormDefault="unqualified" version="1.0">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()[starts-with(@name, 'prefix_')]"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()[descendant::node()/@*[starts-with(., 'prefix_')]]"/>
        </xs:schema>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="xsd:schema/node()[starts-with(@name, 'prefix_')]">
        <xsl:copy-of select="current()"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="xsd:schema/node()[descendant::node()/@*[starts-with(., 'prefix_')]]">
        <xsl:copy-of select="current()"/>
    </xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Good question +1. Even if there is an accepted answer you might be interested in testing my answer which seems using a much simpler approach.

Comment: Good question, +1. If you pay attention, you will notice that two of the answers, including the currently selected one produce wrong results even with small variations of the provided XML document ...

Comment: @Dimitre, that's not true anymore, at least for my answer. Also note that you have provided confusing variations of the XML documents.

Comment: @empo: Of course they are confusing ... :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have fixed the **silly** error noticed by @Dimitre.

Now, the following transform:

```
 <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="xs:schema/*[
        not(starts-with(@name,'prefix_'))
            and
            not(.//*/@*[starts-with(.,'prefix_')])]"/>

    <xsl:template match="*[
        not(*) 
            and
        not(@*[starts-with(.,'prefix_')])
            and
        not(ancestor::*[starts-with(@name,'prefix_')])
        ]"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

given this input (slightly modified to cover much more complex cases):

```
<xml>
    <xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

        <!-- a comment -->

        <node name="prefix_a">
            <element />
            <element attr="asdf" />
            <element x="y" attr="prefix_attr" />
            <element battr="prefix_battr" y="x"/>
        </node>

        <node name="prefix_b">
            <node>
                <element />
                <element battr="prefix_bttr" />
                <element hattr="prefix_cattr" />
            </node>
        </node>

        <node name="c">
            <node>
                <node>
                    <node>
                        <node>
                            <element attr="qwerty" />
                            <element attr="zxvc" />
                            <element attr="asdf" />
                            <element battr="prefix_bttr" x="y"/>
                            <element flattr="prefix_hattr" y="x"/>
                        </node>
                    </node>
                </node>
            </node>
        </node>

        <node name="d">
            <element />
            <element attr="asdf" />
            <element shattr="prefix_shattr" />
            <element cattr="prefix_battr" />
        </node>

        <node name="e">
            <element />
            <element attr="asdf" />
        </node>

    </xs:schema>
</xml>
```

produces:

```
<xml>
   <xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
      <node name="prefix_a">
         <element/>
         <element attr="asdf"/>
         <element x="y" attr="prefix_attr"/>
         <element battr="prefix_battr" y="x"/>
      </node>
      <node name="prefix_b">
         <node>
            <element/>
            <element battr="prefix_bttr"/>
            <element hattr="prefix_cattr"/>
         </node>
      </node>
      <node name="c">
         <node>
            <node>
               <node>
                  <node>
                     <element battr="prefix_bttr" x="y"/>
                     <element flattr="prefix_hattr" y="x"/>
                  </node>
               </node>
            </node>
         </node>
      </node>
      <node name="d">
         <element shattr="prefix_shattr"/>
         <element cattr="prefix_battr"/>
      </node>
   </xs:schema>
</xml>
```

Comment: There is an obvious error -- please, correct. Test your code with elements that have more than one attribute and an attribute that isn't the first has value that starts with the interesting string...

Comment: And the templates are 3 -- not two.

Comment: what is the purpose of the "not(*)"?

Answer (score 1):

In the case of the nodes that which have a **@name** attribute starting with **prefix_** you can leave the identity transform to do its work. So, you only need to override the case for elements who don't have a **@name** starting with **prefix_**.

```
<xsl:template match="xs:schema/node()[not(starts-with(@name, 'prefix'))]">
```

To copy only the descendants with any attribute that starts with "prefix_", you will also need to copy any node that may not have an attribute itself, but does itself have a descendant meeting the criteria.

```
<xsl:apply-templates 
   select="@*|
      node()[descendant-or-self::*[count(@*[starts-with(., 'prefix')]) &gt; 0]]" 
   mode="attr" />
```

So, here, you use the **mode** attribute when you apply the templates, so you can override the behaviour on matching the descendants too

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()" mode="attr">
```

Here is the full XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

   <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:apply-templates />
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="xs:schema/node()[not(starts-with(@name, 'prefix'))]">
      <xsl:if test="descendant-or-self::*[count(@*[starts-with(., 'prefix')]) &gt; 0]">
         <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()[descendant-or-self::*[count(@*[starts-with(., 'prefix')]) &gt; 0]]" mode="attr" />
         </xsl:copy>
      </xsl:if>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="@*|node()" mode="attr">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*[starts-with(., 'prefix')]|node()[descendant-or-self::*[count(@*[starts-with(., 'prefix')]) &gt; 0]]" mode="attr"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to your input XML, the output is as follows:

```
<xml>
   <xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
      <node name="prefix_a">
         <element/>
         <element attr="asdf"/>
         <element attr="prefix_attr"/>
         <element battr="prefix_battr"/>
      </node>
      <node name="prefix_b">
         <node>
            <element/>
            <element battr="prefix_bttr"/>
            <element hattr="prefix_cattr"/>
         </node>
      </node>
      <node name="c">
         <node>
            <node>
               <node>
                  <node>
                     <element battr="prefix_bttr"/>
                     <element flattr="prefix_hattr"/>
                  </node>
               </node>
            </node>
         </node>
      </node>
      <node name="d">
         <element shattr="prefix_shattr"/>
         <element cattr="prefix_battr"/>
      </node>
   </xs:schema>
</xml>
```

Comment: this should not return a `/xs:schema/node()` that does not match any conditions. see my edits above for `<!-- a comment -->` and `<node name="e">`. how to remove these from the output?

Comment: I've added an **xsl:if** to the first template match to exclude the main nodes where they have no matching descendants

Comment: awesome! I understand. can I ask why you are using `count() > 0`?

Comment: You are right. That count() > 0 is unnecessary! Not sure why I put that in.

Answer (score 1):

None of the other two answers works correctly if the attribute whose value starts with "prefix_" isn't the first (and only) attribute of its parent element!

**This transformation** (besides correct seems to be the shortest and simplest -- no modes and no explicit conditional instructions):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match=
   "node[@name[not(starts-with(.,'prefix_'))]
        and
          not(descendant::*[@*[starts-with(.,'prefix_')]])
         ]"/>

  <xsl:template match=
   "*[ancestor::node[@name[not(starts-with(.,'prefix_'))]]
    and
      not(*)
    and
      not(@*[starts-with(.,'prefix_')])
     ]"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the following XML document** (the provided one, but extended so that some elements have two attributes -- look at `<node name="c">`):

```
<xml>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

  <!-- a comment -->

  <node name="prefix_a">
    <element />
    <element attr="asdf" />
    <element attr="prefix_attr" />
    <element battr="prefix_battr" />
  </node>

  <node name="prefix_b">
    <node>
      <element />
      <element battr="prefix_bttr" />
      <element hattr="prefix_cattr" />
    </node>
  </node>

  <node name="c">
    <node>
      <node>
        <node>
          <node>
            <element attr="qwerty" />
            <element attr="zxvc" />
            <element attr="asdf" />
            <element battr="prefix_bttr" />
            <element flattr="prefix_hattr" />
          </node>
        </node>
      </node>
    </node>
  </node>

  <node name="d">
    <element />
    <element attr="asdf" />
    <element shattr="prefix_shattr" />
    <element cattr="prefix_battr" />
  </node>

  <node name="e">
    <element />
    <element attr="asdf" />
  </node>
</xs:schema>
</xml>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
<xml>
   <xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><!-- a comment --><node name="prefix_a">
         <element/>
         <element attr="asdf"/>
         <element attr="prefix_attr"/>
         <element battr="prefix_battr"/>
      </node>
      <node name="prefix_b">
         <node>
            <element/>
            <element battr="prefix_bttr"/>
            <element hattr="prefix_cattr"/>
         </node>
      </node>
      <node name="c">
         <node>
            <node>
               <node>
                  <node>
                     <element y="z" battr="prefix_bttr"/>
                     <element x="y" flattr="prefix_hattr"/>
                  </node>
               </node>
            </node>
         </node>
      </node>
      <node name="d">
         <element shattr="prefix_shattr"/>
         <element cattr="prefix_battr"/>
      </node>
   </xs:schema>
</xml>
```

**Do note** that the solutions in the other two answers lose either the element `<node name="c">` and its complete subtree, or lose some of the attributes.

Comment: Now that I fixed my errors, you should fix your ones :). Please provide correct sample input, as it seems from your input/output samples that your transform adds unwanted attributes not present in the input. Moreover, OP does not want to copy comment nodes.

Comment: Apart my silly error and the usage of identity transform, don't you think this answer is the exact copy of mine?

Comment: @empo: if you have really corrected your error, maybe it has become a copy of mine :). It definitely wasn't -- before your correction. :)

Comment: @empo: Now your code seems much more like mine, but there are still subtle differences.

Comment: this answer does not work for me. what about `<node name="e">` as specified in the input?

Comment: @corrinado_swam: You have specified that the element `<node name="e">` shouldn't be in the output (see what you provided as desired output). This is exactly what this solution does -- there is no  `<node name="e">` in the output. So, have you made a mistake in your question? If so, then better than saying: "this answer does not work for me", edit your question and notify all repliers about the change.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev I'm sorry, but you never included `<node name="e">` in your test input. of course it wasn't in your output. please verify this.

Comment: @corrinado_swam: I see, Maybe I just missed this in the input I published. I just verified that with this new element the same transformations - not modified at all -- produces the wanted answer (the node is omitted in the output). I will put the full XML document in my answer, but apart from this there is no problem with the transformation. What problem do you observe?

Comment: @corrinado_swam: I edited the answer and modified the source XML document -- now it has the `<node name="e">` . Once again, what problem do you see?

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev your does not work with namespaces or comments. try the edits from my input document in the OP